# Android - Determine tile bitmap based on surrounding tiles

Tags: android, tiles, terrain, procedural-generation

I have been working on a tile-based terrain generation system , and have run into a bit of a snag.  I am hoping to create a series of transition tiles that will mark the transition between water and land, and am having trouble figuring out an efficient way to figure out which tile should be which.

My first attempt (illustrated below) would basically run each tile through a series of if statements to figure out which one it should be.  The main problem with this is that, with a 100 tile x 100 tile world map, it would be running though 10,000 iterations, accessing the data on the 8 surrounding tiles (80,000 operations), and then running through up to four if statements (320,000 operations).  It just seems to me that this would be horribly inefficient and slow.

The upside of this method is that it would only run on land tiles, and would first check to make sure that it is adjacent to at least one water tile, which would greatly reduce the number of required operations.

Here's the basic chart I drew up that walks through the surrounding tiles and picks out the appropriate tile.

[image: Attempt 1 layout]

My second idea was to essentially start walking through tiles and, once I hit a coastal tile, follow the coast in both directions, assigning tiles as I went.  this method would make sure that the tile hasn't already been figured out before starting.  The problem with this is that, one, I can't figure out quite how that would work, and two, as a result I have no idea how efficient it would be.

A friend told me about a third method that might work.  It takes water tiles and sets them equal to 0 and land tiles, which are set to 1.  Then, it takes the surrounding tiles and numbers them from 1 to 9.  From there were walk through them and create a string on 0's and 1's:

```
W   W   W
W   L   L
L   L   L
```

would be: 000011111

0*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^6 + 1*2^7 + 1*2^8

0*1 + 0*2 + 0*4 + 0*8 + 1*16 + 1*32 + 1*64 + 1*128 + 1*126  = 496

The theory is that I would assign the tile associated with that combination the number 496 and load it in response.  The problem is that each edge has 13 or 14 combinations taht would result in its use.  for instance:

```
W   W   L           L   W   W
W   L   L    and    W   L   L   Both need the same tile as the above example, but
L   L   L           L   L   L   produce different numbers.
```

Essentially, to make this method work I would have to figure out the final number for each possible combination of water and land that would result in a particular tile, and then run the final number through a series of ifs / cases to pick out the appropriate bitmap.  This would be just as, or more, inefficient than the if blocks.

So, coming to the actual question in all of this.  Does anyone know of an alternate way of doing this, or a way to make either of these methods more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried either solution and tested it for speed yet?  Are you sure you aren't attempting premature optimization?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't had the opportunity to.  I'm looking for an alternate method based on the assumption that running through all those if statements would be very time consuming.  I will take a pass at the first method this evening.

Comment: @Zathross Well, looks like you were right.  I ran it through initial testing and the total return time for running through every square on the map, collecting the information on the surrounding tiles, checking for water and then assigning the proper bitmap takes a whopping 60 ms on average.  However, once I looked at it in the game, I realized that I was nowhere close to accounting for all the possible land-water configurations.  I'll probably be doubling or tripling the number of tiles needed, which may lead me to make an attempt with the third method again.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just wrote this part of a game I started working on. Took me a little while to think of the solution but when I did I couldn't believe I didn't think of it earlier. If you think about it, each tile has 8 possible "connections":

```
1 2 3
4 x 5
6 7 8
```

And each connection can either contain a tile it connects to or not. So this is sweet, it means its a very binary system and we can represent every combination with  8 bits (or 1 byte), and we know every combination is represented sequentially from 0-255, so we can easily use a lookup table (well, lookup array) to find the correct image. Though this does mean there are 256 possible combinations of connection (not 256 different images mind you, like you said above different combinations will use the same tile graphic) we have to generate. What I did (and I recommend), is wrote a small script to generate the lookup array.

Now the way to maintain this is that every tile has an 8 length array of the tiles it is connected to. When loading the map, fill in the "connections" array of the tiles as you go. Once a tile has all its connections (or once all tiles are loaded) then calculate the "connection mask" or "connection value" for each tile  (which is the index into the lookup array). This is done by looping through the "connections" array and building the mask using bit shifts. After that you should only ever need to do very minimal processing again, and only on the individual tiles that are added/removed/changed and the 8 possible tiles its connected to.

Hope this helps. If you need more details or example code I can provide that later!